# I/O warnings and external entities

Tags: vmware-player, xml, io

when entering the input:

```
sudo /usr/bin/vmplayer &
```

I receive the following error in my terminal's verbose output:

```
I/O warning: failed to load external entity "/etc/VMware/hostd/proxy.xml"
```

So my first question may seem pretty stupid but that's just my style now days, why is this file referred to as an "external" entity by my operating system's I/O?

And secondly, how do I determine how to format an xml file appropriately on a case by case basis?